# How do I make a Icecast live stream play at accurate time?

Tags: icecast

I've just tried setting up Icecast2, alongside with Darkice.

I notice that when I play from the live stream, the audio seems to be 30 seconds later than it should be.

How do I make a Icecast live stream play at the same time as the audio it's providing? I understand that a lot of live streams are not always accurate, such as online radio but is there a feature when I can get the most accurate time?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to read through these two answers to gain a better understanding of what is at play here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36929851/2648865

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17151097/2648865

You *can* reduce latency somewhat, but it will require control of as much of the whole chain as possible. It also will come at the expense of stream reliability.

It would certainly help if you would explain what you are trying to achieve with this on a higher level, as it might even be that Icecast is unsuitable for what you want.